# ORA-28595: Extproc agent : Invalid DLL Path error

Tags: c, plsql, oracle11g

Giving error when running a c function from plsql.
tnsnames.ora and listener.ora files have been configured perfectly 
still giving error.Please help

listener.ora-----

```
    SID_LIST_LISTENER =
      (SID_LIST =
        (SID_DESC =
          (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
          (ORACLE_HOME = D:\app\Pacific\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
          (PROGRAM = EXTPROC1521)
          (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ANY")
        )

      )

    LISTENER =
      (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
        (DESCRIPTION =
          (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
          (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Pacific)(PORT = 1521))
        )
      )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = D:\app\Pacific

tnsnames.ora

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

cfile-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int FindFact(int num)
{
    int i,f=1;

    for(i=1;i<=num;i++)
      f=f*i;

     return f;
getch();
}
```

library creation-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE LIBRARY HR.EXTDLL
 IS 'D:\Labs\test.dll';
```

function to access-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION HR.F_fact(P_STRING varchar2)
RETURN number
AS LANGUAGE C
LIBRARY HR.EXTDLL
NAME "FindFact"
PARAMETERS (P_STRING string);
```

calling block-

```
declare
l number:=5;
n number;
begin
n:=f_fact(l);
end;
```

Please help.

Comment: Your function is not correct. Its not returning anything in the body.

Comment: Sir, the function is for calling a external procedure and syntax is according to specification.The value would be returned from external procedure.I checked it from the advanced plslql developer guide book.If you want me to change anything in the code.please suggest.

Comment: @XING Sir,any suggestions?